# Organizing/manipulating a string using JAVA

Tags: java

I'm filling a string with words and commas, and i want to get rid of the last comma and the one before it i want to replace with and.

ex:

```
 now -> "john,mary,paul,bla,etc,"
 what i want -> "john,mary,paul,bla and etc"
```

I'd like to know the best way to doit, can anyone help ?

Comment: What code do you have now?

Comment: Both tasks (getting rid of the final comma, and replacing the next-to-last comma with "and") can be done pretty easily with [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) and regexes. If you don't know the basics of regexes, look at this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).  The second task is best done by searching for `,` followed by a capture group of non-`,` characters, after the last comma is eliminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of solutions:

```
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder("john,mary,paul,bla,etc,");

int prevIndex = strBuilder.indexOf("etc");

strBuilder.replace(prevIndex-1, prevIndex, " and ");

int nextIndex = strBuilder.indexOf("etc");

strBuilder.replace(nextIndex+3, nextIndex+4, ".");

System.out.println("Result: "+strBuilder.toString());
```

Comment: This would be more generally applicable if you used "strBuilder.lastIndexOf(',') to find the appropriate cut points, rather than searching for "etc".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a neater and more generalized way of doing this:

```
String str = "john,mary,paul,bla,etc,";

String[] splitStr = str.split(",");
String[] arrayWithAllExceptLast = java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(splitStr, 0, splitStr.length - 1);
String last = splitStr[splitStr.length - 1];
String finalString = org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.join(arrayWithAllExceptLast, ",") + " and " + last;
```

You need apache commons to do this, of course, but everybody should have apache commons in their toolbox, it's essential.

Comment: Java 8 has [`join`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) now--no need for Apache Commons.

Comment: @ajb Thanks for the pointer. So they've finally added it! Though I shall be waiting quite a while before installing Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it:

```
str = str.replaceAll(",$", "").replaceAll(",([^,]+)$", " and $1");
```

The first `replaceAll` just replaces the last character with an empty string if it's a comma.  (`$` in the regex means "match the end of the input string").  Now that the last comma is gone, the second `replaceAll` will look for the last remaining comma followed a group of non-comma characters, at the end of the string; it treats the non-commma characters as a group.  The whole string is then replaced by `" and "` followed by the group of non-comma characters (`$1` in the replacement expression).

A slightly different regex:

```
str = str.replaceAll(",$", "").replaceAll(",(?=[^,]+$)", " and ");
```

In this case, the second regex has a lookahead.  So it will look for a comma that is *followed by* a sequence of non-comma characters followed by the end of the string; however, the text in the lookahead part isn't considered part of the matched string, and therefore it won't be replaced.  So it's sufficient just to replace that `","` with `" and "`.